# Verify assigning of material to all parts in a assembly

Tags: solidworks

is there any provision in SolidWorks to check if all parts in an assembly is assigned material, rather than individually checking each part under the design tree? It becomes tedious to check individually when there are too many parts

Comment: Define the material for each part as the part is defined then they are complete.

Comment: Insert a BOM and add a column for the material - will quickly see where the blanks are